# How to accurately judge the size of the View(ViewGroup)

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want to custom a ViewGroup that has a left FrameLayout.
the framelayout can be modified the size.
this is my code

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);
    final int actionIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(ev);

    boolean wantTouchEvents = true;
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            Log.i("action_down", "action_down");
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();
            mInitialMotionX = x;
            mInitialMotionY = y;
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View view = getChildAt(i);
                if (isDrawerView(view)) {
                    LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                    params.width = DRAWER_WIDTH + (int) (x - mInitialMotionX);
                    view.setLayoutParams(params);
                }

            }
            break;
        }
```

in the ontouchevent() method, when action_move ,i set the width of the framelayout.but i can't judge the width that i set. because the width of the framelayout change is not linear.
example, i set the max width of the framelayout is 300dp.
when the width is becoming,if i move in the x quickly, the width of the framelayout may be 310 or 330 or other.
i just want to judge the size of the framelayout accurately.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yxcq.png)

Comment: why do you call setLayoutParams inside onTouchEvent?

Comment: @pskink i change the width of the FrameLayout,so i call setLayoutParams()to change the width of the framelayout